# does a HP keyboard KB-0316 support usb as well?

Tags: keyboard

I ended up with a small pile of brand new HP keyboards and mice and unfortunate for me they are all ps2. I was looking to buy ps2->usb adapters but since they are passive adapters they will possibly not work.

I know the ps2 optical mice I have will not convert correctly on a passive adapter. The keyboard is what I am unsure about. Despite my best efforts I cannot find any documentation for the thing on HP's site. Even when you select the original computer that this gear came with there is no appendix documentation provided that covers the keyboard specifically.

So I was hoping someone else out there that uses these might know and can save me from possibly buying adapters I can't use. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That keyboard is as standard as it gets. While as far as my experience goes I would say that it will work with no problems, my recommendation goes for a ps/2 to USB signal CONVERTER, not a regular passive adapter.

The ps/2 to USB signal CONVERTER use an integrated circuit (pre-programmed chip) to actively translate the ps/2 keyboard signal and convert it into a USB keyboard signal.

This allows the ps/2 keyboard to be automatically recognized by the OS as if it were a standard USB keyboard, thus using the built-in OS drivers for a USB keyboard.

---

The market is a bit misleading about this, converter and adapter gets mixed a lot, but one can easily tell the difference by looking at the price or the shape:

Passive adapter: $1.00 ~ $2.00

Active Signal Converter: $7.00 ~ $15.00

[image]

Comment: Thank you Zuul. Somehow I missed the active converter in my searches. Now you say it converts keyboard signals, what about mice?

Comment: @TWood There are signal converters that provide entry for keyboard and mouse, with an exit to USB: **e.g.** [TRENDnet USB to PS/2 Converter TU-PS2 (White)](http://www.amazon.com/TRENDnet-USB-Converter-TU-PS2-White/dp/B0007T27HI).